# What is this biplane from an old photograph?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

[image: Image of airplane]
*Copyright photo by Real Photographs No 334*

Answer (score 5):

[Gloster Gladiator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloster_Gladiator), also [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrpWcm8V3k4).

(Answer taken from comment by [mins](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/3201/mins).)

Comment: Looks like the same aircraft, G37, the prototype?

Comment: [Same photo](https://www.picclickimg.com/d/w1600/pict/254010672608_/Real-Photo-Postcard-Gloster-Gladiator-Aviation.jpg) as a postcard ([source](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Real-Photo-Postcard-Gloster-Gladiator-Aviation-/254010672608?nma=true&si=rFXq%252BrT31qvdtowH4k6Xpsagyx8%253D&orig_cvip=true&nordt=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557)).